# Javascript: Sort by first characters of an an array

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, parsing, numbers

Bear with me, I'm still kinda new to javascript.. I am trying to sort a list of save-game codes to be sorted by their first parse of the element.

```
var vList =["1|846|Doc|2|0|false|", "11|203|Derik|7|3|false|", "21|670|Mike|5|5|true|", "13|11|Ron|0|0|false|", "9|1000|Blood|9|9|true|"];
var vParse;
for (i = 0; i < (vParse.length); i++)
    var vParse[i]= vList.split('|');

// then somehow sort all the data based on vParse[0]?
```

I tried a few sorting submissions from other folks, but I couldn't get it to ignore all the font after the first parse. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: You just want to sort the array based on the first number before the pipe ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.sort` and just split on the pipe, get the first item, and when subtracting the strings are converted to numbers anyway

```js
var vList =["1|846|Doc|2|0|false|", "11|203|Derik|7|3|false|", "21|670|Mike|5|5|true|", "13|11|Ron|0|0|false|", "9|1000|Blood|9|9|true|"];

vList.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.split('|')[0] - b.split('|')[0];
});

console.log(vList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some like that:

```
vList.sort( function( a, b ) {
    return parseInt( a.split( '|' )[ 0 ] ) - parseInt( b.split( '|' )[ 0 ] );
} );
```

You can read more about [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) methods.

Comment: Due to javascript type coercion, in this case '-' on strings, the parseInt's not required.

Comment: @Keith, sure, I just thought that `parseInt` method is more obvious for beginner

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
vList.map(function(el){return {sortBy : parseInt(el.split('|')[0]), original : el}}).sort(function(a,b){return a.sortBy - b.sortBy}).map(function(el){return el.original})
```